# The date $8.8.6.4$

Tags: mathematics

> The date $8.8.64$, meaning August $8, \; 1964$ is a very interesting date, because the product first $2$ numbers equals the third.
>
> ### Can you find the year of the twentieth century which gives the maximum number dates of this kind?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by maximum dates?

Comment: Maximum number of dates in that kind.

Comment: Oh I see!!! Fairs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list of all the dates matching the pattern are here:

> https://www.pastebin.com/hGr9QsJK

The most common years are $24$ and $60$ occurring $7$ times

The years and their respective frequencies are given below:

> https://www.pastebin.com/6ddZPaxN

Comment: Please moderate your language. We aren't supposed to use these vulgar words here. Kindly delete those comments. And it is not about getting the answer first. Those who sees first has higher chance of answering first if he has the skills. Solving puzzles must be for its own sake. @Deepthinker101

Comment: Look at my edit...

Answer (score 2):

> 24.4.96

I wonder if this is the right answer to your question?

1960?

Comment: No. There is another year with more such kinds of dates. But good, you have got a nice year. ;-)

Comment: New answer btw

Comment: Your question specified only one year